# Calling function from different class gives TypeError: missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, tkinter

I was trying to build something where I wanted to give separate class to each frames. Now when I called onSet function of AddWidgets class it shows an

```
ERROR: TypeError: onSet() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'
```

What am I doing wrong? And how to solve this? My Code is given below:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Class Function")
        self.master.wm_iconbitmap('icon.ico')
        self.master.geometry("360x240+100+100")
        self.frame1 = ttk.Frame(self.master)
        self.frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=16, pady=16)
        self.frame2 = ttk.Frame(self.master)
        self.frame2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=16, pady=16)

        self.add = AddWidgets(self.frame1)
        self.edit = EditWidgets(self.frame2)


class AddWidgets:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.label1 = ttk.Label(self.master, text="0")
        self.label1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=4, pady=4)

    def onSet(self, text):
        self.label1.configure(text=text)


class EditWidgets:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        def onEdit():
            self.send_text = self.entry_text.get()
            AddWidgets.onSet(self.send_text)

        self.entry_text = tk.StringVar()
        self.entry1 = ttk.Entry(self.master, textvariable=self.entry_text)
        self.entry1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=4, pady=4)
        self.button1 = ttk.Button(self.master, text="edit", command=onEdit)
        self.button1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=4, pady=4)



def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MainWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am new to Python and tkinter. I want to build a desktop app/software. I want to develop the software by following MVC pattern. So any resource for MVC in tkinter and suggestions on how can I improve my coding, software development process would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `onSet` requires the instance of the class as a first argument, while you're only passing the `text` argument. So when you call your `onSet` method you should pass the instance of the `AddWidgets` class as first argument.
You're instantiating this class in the `MainWindow` class:

```
self.add = AddWidgets(self.frame1)
```

So you should pass the `self.add` variable to the `onSet` function. In order to do that you should have your `EditWidget` class accept an additional parameter `widget`:

```
class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Class Function")
        self.master.wm_iconbitmap('icon.ico')
        self.master.geometry("360x240+100+100")
        self.frame1 = ttk.Frame(self.master)
        self.frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=16, pady=16)
        self.frame2 = ttk.Frame(self.master)
        self.frame2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=16, pady=16)

        self.add = AddWidgets(self.frame1)
        self.edit = EditWidgets(self.frame2, self.add) <--Add parameter self.add


class AddWidgets:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.label1 = ttk.Label(self.master, text="0")
        self.label1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=4, pady=4)

    def onSet(self, text):
        self.label1.configure(text=text)


class EditWidgets:
    def __init__(self, master, widget): <-- add parameter widget 
        self.master = master
        self.create_widgets()
        self.widget = widget

    def create_widgets(self):
        def onEdit():
            self.send_text = self.entry_text.get()
            self.widget.onSet(self.send_text) <--call onSet from widget instance
[...]
```

EDIT:
If you want to create different tabs, all with the same widgets, one approach could be the following: you create a `MainWindow` class, where you add all the tabs to your window using the `Notebook` class.

Then you create a `Add Widgets` class that adds the required widgets to a frame. You instantiate this class on each of the created tabs, in order to populate them with the widgets.

In order to get the values of the variables you set in each tab you can write a method `getEntryValue` (or whatever name) that returns the value set on the entry. Something like this:

```
class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Class Function")

        self.master.geometry("360x240+100+100")

        n = ttk.Notebook(master)
        self.f1 = ttk.Frame(n)   # Create first tab
        self.f2 = ttk.Frame(n)   # Create second tab
        n.add(self.f1, text='One')
        n.add(self.f2, text='Two')     
        n.pack()        

        self.widget1 = AddWidgets(self.f1)
        self.widget2 = AddWidgets(self.f2)


class AddWidgets:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        def onEdit():
            send_text = self.entry_text.get()
            self.label1.configure(text = send_text)

        self.label1 = ttk.Label(self.master, text="0")
        self.label1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=4, pady=4)

        self.entry_text = tk.StringVar()
        self.entry1 = ttk.Entry(self.master, textvariable=self.entry_text)
        self.entry1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=4, pady=4)

        self.button1 = ttk.Button(self.master, text="edit", command=onEdit)
        self.button1.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=4, pady=4)

    def getEntryText(self):
        return self.entry_text.get()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. It helps.
But now if I have 10/15 classes and want to do the similar thing in all of them I would have to pass every class to another class.
Is that a good idea? Is there any better approach that I can follow?

Comment: @ParthoDas yes, there probably is a better approach, but we would need to know a bit more about what you're trying to achieve in order to give you the best advice.

Comment: Perhaps one idea could be to merge the `AddWidget` and `EditWidget` classes.

Comment: I want to build a software where there will be 7/8 tabs. each tabs will do there own individual calculations. but while calculating values of each tab will be needed in another tab. I wanted to make each tab a different class. that makes it easier to code for me.

Comment: Thanks for helping. But this is not what I am wanting.